# sed with external script file - How to apply shell variables?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, variable, variable-substitution

Directly on the command line, this works:

```
$sed "s/a/X/;s/X/&a&/" file
```

and so does using shell variables:

```
$varin=a ; varout=X ; sed "s/$varin/$varout/;s/$varout/&$varin&/" file
```

However using an external script file

```
$sed -f script.sed file
```

Only the "hardcoded" approach works

```
$cat script.sed
s/a/X/
s/X/&a&/
```

While shell variables are not expanded

```
$cat script.sed
s/$varin/$varout/
a/$varout/&$varin&/

$varin=a ; varout=X ; sed -f script.sed file
#-> variables in script.sed not interpreted; output unchanged
```

**How to achieve the interpretation of shell variables within an external `sed` script file?**

I quite understand that `sed` itself cannot interpret the shell variables, but how could I preprocess the script (in a save manner) to once run it through `bash` for resolving variables? Maybe one could import them to `sed` with a command at the beginning?

The following approaches were not fruitful (using `bash`):

- using `export varin=a ; export varout=X`
- via `sed -e $(cat sed.script) file`: works for single-line script, fails on multi-line ones, even with comment as first line
- `sed -f <(cat script.sed) file`
- `eval sed -f script.sed file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `envsubst` to replace the variables in your script with the intended values before running `sed`.

```
$ cat script.sed
s/$varin/$varout/
s/$varout/&$varin&/
```

Replacing the strings `$varin` or `${varin}` and `$varout` or `${varout}` in `script.sed` with their variables values:

```
$ varin='a' varout='X' envsubst '$varin $varout' <script.sed
s/a/X/
s/X/&a&/
```

The `sed` command using a process substitution:

```
sed -f <(varin='a' varout='X' envsubst '$varin $varout' <script.sed) file
```

Comment: Nice program, any dangers know regarding e.g. special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Heredoc to the rescue:

```
varin=a; varout=X
sed -f - <<_CODE_    file
s/$varin/$varout/
_CODE_
```

But mind you, this approach is fraught with errors/incorrect results , if the shell vars being parachuted inside w/o proper sanitization. Take for example, what would happen if varout contained the character `&` or `/` etc.